# Iphone vs ipad mobile phone site redirection

Tags: iphone, ipad

We have an issue, with our mobile banking site.

Users with iphone and other mobile phones are re-directed correctly to the mobile vesrion of our internet banking
The issue is with users that have Ipads they get redirect to the mobile banking site aswell instead of the the normal internet banking site.

How do we fix this problem?

Comment: One option I like to find on a mobile version of site, especially when using my iPhone 4, is a button or link to switch to the "full" site and back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not someone is visiting your webpage on an iPad can be done like so

via JavaScript:

```
var userHasiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

PHP:

```
$userHasiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');
```

Both of these are essentially checking the User Agent string for the existence of the string "iPad".

Comment: it looks like it;s a browser issue...since on of our clients used IE on ipad and it worked fine.it looks like is a safari issue?